# Dynamically generated sql pivot with calculated columns general methodology

Tags: sql

I have the following scenario:
Generation of a pivot with dynamic columns which I can manage via generating dynamic sql either on the client or in a stored procedure

I then need to calculate additional values based on the values already calculated by the pivot.

Here is the sql to generate all the steps in the process :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.departmentStats', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.departmentStats;

CREATE TABLE departmentStats
([Facility] varchar(50), [Department] varchar(50),[Stat] varchar(5),      
[January] int, [February] int, [March] int);

INSERT INTO departmentStats
([Facility],[Department],[Stat], [January], [February], [March])
VALUES
('f1','d1','Stat1', 90, 40, 60),
('f1','d1','Stat2', 30, 20, 10);

select 'Original Data' as src,* from departmentStats

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#pivotstats', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #pivotstats;

 CREATE TABLE #pivotstats
(facility varchar(50),department varchar(50),stat VARCHAR(50),period   
 varchar(50),value  int)

 insert into #pivotstats
select facility,department,Stat, period, value
from departmentStats
unpivot
(
  value
  for Period in (January, February, March)
) u 

select 'Original after unpivot' as src,* from #pivotstats


IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.departmentStats2', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.departmentStats2;

CREATE TABLE departmentStats2
([Facility] varchar(50), [Department] varchar(50),[Period] varchar(20),    
[stat1] int, [stat2] int, [Sum] numeric(10,2),[Division] numeric(10,2));

insert into departmentStats2
select
facility
,department
,period
,Stat1
,stat2
,Stat1+Stat2 as [sum]
,case when Stat2<>0 then cast(Stat1/Stat2 AS numeric) else 0.0 end as  
 division
 from #pivotstats
  Pivot(
   sum(value) 
    for Stat in ([Stat1],[Stat2])
  ) 
  as x

select 'Added formula columns' as src,* from departmentStats2

select  'Union and repivot' as src,* from (
select 
facility
,department
,Period
,'Stat1' as Stat
,stat1 as value
from departmentStats2

union all
select 
facility
,department
,Period
,'Stat2' as Stat
,stat2 as value
from departmentStats2

union all

select 
facility
,department
,Period
,'sum' as Stat
,[SUM] as value
from departmentStats2

union all
select 
facility
,department
,Period
,'Division' as Stat
,[Division] as value
from departmentStats2
 ) as bunion
pivot(
    sum(value)
    for Period in (January, February, March)
)as P
```

I have only included three periods for the sample.

[image]

I have no doubt that I can generate SQL in this format at will.

I don't foresee any real issues considering my data source will be static (updated daily) and heavily indexed. I don't yet have a full data set ready to test but I will update the q when I do

The reason for the pivot olympics is that the final output is actually as spreadsheet which uses index/match to lookup the values for each stat by facility/department/name to produce graphs and charts

Opinions ? 
Obvious flaws?
Is this better done in C# by generating a class at runtime?
Remember the idea is to provide the ability to add stats based on known stats with a minimum of effort.

Here is a better way to do the last step using cross apply instead of union all

```
select  'Union and repivot' as src,* from (

select       
 departmentStats2.Facility,
departmentStats2.Department,Departmentstats2.period,x.stat,x.value
from
 departmentStats2
  cross Apply(
        values(Facility,Department,Period,'1_Sales',Sales),
               (Facility,Department,Period,'2_Cost',Cost),
               (Facility,Department,Period,'3_GrossProfit',GrossProfit),
               (Facility,Department,Period,'4_GPP',GPP)
) as x(Facility,Department,Period,Stat,[Value])
 )as P
    pivot(
       sum(value)
       for Period in (January, February, March)
    )as P
    order by Facility,department,Stat
```

from
http://sqlsunday.com/2014/03/02/unpivot-using-cross-apply/

Comment: For the person who knocked me for no research effort. The research was all performed in order to come up with the method in and of itself. I appologize for not quoting every post I have read over the last few days where I have only found out how to create the dynamic pivot by creating a stored procedure with dynamic sql that inserts the field names into the pivot clause. AFAIK everything else here is something I just came up with and want to see what others think.

Comment: Here is a better way to do the union all and pivot for the last step

Comment: Are you experiencing a specific problem with your code or are you asking us to [review it](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Asking for opinions on the General method. The combination of pivot/

Comment: UnPivot with the addition of more columns possibly by .Net ADO or dynamic SQL whichever "feels" better per user taste.